# Create Map of strings form typeid, variadic template

Tags: c++

so I am creating a small Framework to create StateMachines. This Framework uses as for now a TransitionTable like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> inner_table;
typedef std::map<std::string, inner_table> complete_table;
complete_table test = {
        {
            "State1",{
                { "Event1", "State2" },
                { "Event2", "State3" },
                { "Event3", "State3" }
            }
        },
        {
            "State2",{
                { "Event1", "State3" },
                { "Event2", "State1" },
                { "Event3", "State3" }
            }
        },
        {
            "State3",{
                { "Event1", "State1" },
                { "Event2", "State2" }
            }
        }
    };
```

This works fine for me. The States are all seperate Classes, with a name given with the default Cstr. The only problem with this is: I dont like the way you have to use it.
I come up this:

```
TransitionTable<
                  Current, Event , Next
        Transition<State1, Event1, State2>,
        Transition<State1, Event1, State2>,
        Transition<State1, Event1, State2>,
        Transition<State1, Event1, State2>,
        Transition<State1, Event1, State2>,
        Transition<State1, Event1, State2>,
        Transition<State1, Event1, State2>,
        Transition<State1, Event1, State2>,
        Transition<State1, Event1, State2>,
        Transition<State1, Event1, State2>>
        table{};
```

This Table is more readable and you dont have to give a Name to every State, which can always contain a typo.
Now I created two template Classes, but I dont really know how to go on. I am kinda stuck.

```
#pragma once
#include <map>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> inner_table;
typedef std::map<std::string, inner_table> complete_table;


template<typename CurrentState, typename Event, typename NextState>
struct Transition{

    Transition();
    static complete_table GetTransition();
    std::string m_CurrentState;
    std::string m_Event;
    std::string m_NextState;
};

template <typename CurrentState, typename Event, typename NextState>
Transition<CurrentState, Event, NextState>::Transition() :
    m_CurrentState(typeid(CurrentState).name()),
    m_Event(typeid(Event).name()),
    m_NextState(typeid(NextState).name()) {
}

template <typename CurrentState, typename Event, typename NextState>
complete_table Transition<CurrentState, Event, NextState>::GetTransition() {
    return{ {m_CurrentState,{{m_Event,m_NextState}}} };
}


template<typename Transition, typename ...Args>
class TransitionTable {
public:

    TransitionTable();
    complete_table operator+=(const complete_table& table);
    ~TransitionTable() = default;

private:
    complete_table m_TransitionTable;
};
//Help this is wrong. 
template <typename Transition, typename ... Args>
TransitionTable<Transition, Args...>::TransitionTable() {
    m_TransitionTable = Transition::GiveTransition(); // Wrong but to show the idea
}

template <typename Transition, typename ... Args>
complete_table TransitionTable<Transition, Args...>::operator+=(const complete_table& table) {


}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this approch good or should I redesign it ?
2. Is this approch actually possible?
3. I dont know how to get all the Transitions into the complete_table. I am stuck with the cstr of the TransitionTable class.

I dont need a full solution, only a hint how to go on.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I still want to use strings, but not on the Frontend. I dont know how to get all the Transtions into the complete_map. I edited the Questions to make it more clear.

Comment: That's a way better approach than using strings. Were are you actually stuck? You might want to have a look at the [_State Pattern_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state).

Comment: If you use strings, why do you classes are `template<typename Transition, typename ...Args>
class TransitionTable` templates? What does `Transition` and `Args` represent? Why not just `TransitionTable(complete_table &initialtable = ())` ?

Comment: @HWilmer Years ago (a decade actually) I've created a [framework for state machines](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl) based on the _State Pattern_ mentioned. May be you're interested to inspect it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you, but I already put a lot of effort into it and I want to finish it :)

Comment: @Kamil Cuk I dont know actually. Is there a way to not use strings ?

Comment: From the look of it, you should just use `std::map<std::tuple<State, Event>, State>> transitiontable` where `class State { int number; }` represents a system state and implements some `operator==` and `operator=` (or maybe `State(const State& newstate)`) and `class Event { int number; }` represents an event. You should go with abstraction. When you want to represent a Car you don't `std::string("Car")` you do `class Car { };`. When you want to represent the first event in your system, you don't `string("Event1")` but `Event(1)`.

Comment: Okay. I am setting it up Abstract. ```class State1{State1(): name("State1")}``` Whats the benefit of using tuple? I will look into it and maybe overthink my approch.

Comment: If the `Transition` should represent an action or operation that happens when you want to switch the state from a `State1` to `State2`, why not just implement that inside `State::operator=` (or maybe `State::transition_to(State newstate, Event this_happened)`? Or you could even `std::map<std::tuple<State, Event>, std::tuple<State, std::function<void(*)()>>` where the first tuple represents current state and received event, the second tuple represents new state and the callback to call when transitioning.

Comment: `Whats the benefit of using tuple?` Well, none. Using two maps looks fine verbose. It's just I think it's easier to operate on a tuple then double maps. The `inner_table` map represents a new state for an event for _a specific system state_. It's meaningless without context, we have to know that system state. This subjectively looks to me, like it maps (a tuple of) a specific system state and an event with a new state. But I guess two maps are fine too.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I forgot to mention that the framework i am building is using dynamic states, because I want to create all States in the beginning, but only when they are needed.